# Error while executing git add . in command prompt

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my spring boot application to Heroku. I could see below when I execute `git add .`

```
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=b(2)', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=b(3)', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=core,pm_welcome_home', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=core,pm_welcome_home(1)', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=pm_freetrial_organization_credits', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=pm_freetrial_signup_dialog', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy13,pm_doc_url_service', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy15,sy1i,sy1m,sy27,sy2g,pm_freetrial_verify', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy17,pm_title_service', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy1n,pm_title_service', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy1z,pm_free_trial_popup', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
error: open("New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy2,sy4,sy8,sy9,sy3,sy5,sy6,sy7,syl,syf,syj,syk,syn,syy,pm_shortcut_hints_service,syi,sy1f,sy24,sy2d,sy14,sys,sy19,sy2b,syb,syc,syx,sy18,s"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file 'New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy2,sy4,sy8,sy9,sy3,sy5,sy6,sy7,syl,syf,syj,syk,syn,syy,pm_shortcut_hints_service,syi,sy1f,sy24,sy2d,sy14,sys,sy19,sy2b,syb,syc,syx,sy18,s'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: Below command can be used for file name too long error. git config --system core.longpaths true. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting the length of the name of the file
`"New Project – Google Cloud console_files/m=sy2,sy4,sy8,sy9,sy3,sy5,sy6,sy7,syl,syf,syj,syk,syn,syy,pm_shortcut_hints_service,syi,sy1f,sy24,sy2d,sy14,sys,sy19,sy2b,syb,syc,syx,sy18,s"`
as the error states that the filename is too long.